# Is it OK to pass query results in array to view, instead of SQL resource?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony-1.4

I used to have "flat" scripts. The classic HTML+PHP in one file:

```
$result = mysql_query ('asd');
while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
{
    ?><div><?php echo $record; ?></div>
<?php }
```

I learned that it's bad. But now that I'm working in MVC, the result must be put to an array. And not record, **object** must be put. Isn't it too heavy for the server? It costs much more memory. Or is it accepted, servers can accept it in generally, and I'm the only who makes an ant out of elephant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I learned that it's bad.

Of course it's bad. Because it will always print single word `Array` instead of any data.

> object must be put

it is not true.
there is no reason to use objects where array have to be used.

Anyway,

> Isn't it too heavy for the server?

Nope, it is not. You can use objects all right. Just make sure you are using objects sensibly, for a reason; but not by following some manual saying "use objects".

Finally,

> Is it OK to pass query results in array to view, instead of SQL resource?

Sure. It's the only way possible, even if you are not using MVC.

Answer (score 2):

Writing structured and maintainable code is often more *expensive* in terms of computing power. Anyway in most cases the advantages are much more important.

It’s never a bad idea to think on performance. You can profile your code using tools as Xdebug or XHProf or start simple using execution time measurement via `microtime()`.

You will possibly notice, that you use most time on loading libraries, parsing config files and querying the database, but not on handling of some extra data or objects.